# FIJI Batch Convert does not read images using BioFormats

Tags: imagej, fiji

Basic Q: when trying to use Process -> Batch -> Convert I do not get the popup box that reads 'read images using Bio-Formats.'

I definitely have BioFormats downloaded and it normally works to open my .vsi images. FIJI and Bio-Formats are both updated to their latest versions.